# need solution for 504 error for REST API hosted in cloud

Tags: java, spring, rest, timeout, cloud

When I tested `REST` endpoint locally it is working fine but when we host application in cloud other `APIS` are working fine only one `API` is giving `504 error`. Please give me possible solution. `REST API` is implemented using spring boot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

504 Gateway Time-out issue is generally thrown by a proxy server that means the server is closing connection.
I will need more details like

1. Does the API that you are calling do a long-running task that is taking longer than what proxy time out is set to?
2. Can the task be optimized in any way? - If you cannot optimize the task itself use an Async function or increase the proxy timeout in the server.

Comment: yes it is taking little more time than other API's. but i dont have Callable response so not able to set timeout. Please give some other option so it will work in cloud. Locally its all working fine and i am not able to replicate this issue locally.

Comment: Try to use @Async and make it an Asynchronous call which will return the response instantly but you'll have to write code to handle response in other ways.